# How to use field matching in mongoid query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I am trying to build a search based on names. I am using newbie mongoid user. I want a query in which if i pass "A" it would return me all the names starting with "A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
User.where(:name => /^A/)
```